# Stopping two async method from running concurrently with another

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, async-await

I have two async functions, which I will call `ChangeState()` and `DoThing()`. Each of them awaits downstream async methods. These are called are from event handlers, so they will not block any other code while they execute. If `ChangeState()` is called, it's imperative that `DoThing()` does not do its thing until any previous `ChangeState()` has completed. `ChangeState()` could be called again while it's still executing. Any executions started before `DoThing()` should be completed before `DoThing()` can continue.

The reverse is also true; `ChangeState()` should wait until any previously running `DoStuff()` is complete.

How can I implement this without the danger of deadlocks?

I know awaits are not allowed inside of lock statements and that's for good reasons, which I why I'm not trying to recreate that functionality.

```
async void ChangeState(bool state)
{
 //Wait here until any pending DoStuff() is complete.
 await OutsideApi.ChangeState(state);
}

async void DoStuff()
{
 //Wait here until any pending ChangeState() is complete.
 await OutsideApi.DoStuff();
}
```

Comment: Can `ChangeState` be called before another `ChangeState` call ends? The same for `DoStuff`?

Comment: Yes, there's nothing to stop a 2nd `ChangeState` from being called before the first is done.

Comment: This class could be useful: [ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.concurrentexclusiveschedulerpair?view=netframework-4.7.2) *«Provides task schedulers that coordinate to execute tasks while ensuring that concurrent tasks may run concurrently and exclusive tasks never do.»*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By your requirements seems something like `ReaderWriterLock` could help you. Also, since you have `async` methods you should use `async` lock. Unfortunately, there is no await ready `ReaderWriterLock` lock provided by the .NET framework itself. Luckily, you could take a look at the [AsyncEx](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) library or this [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-7-asyncreaderwriterlock/). The example using `AsyncEx`.

```
var readerWriterLock = new AsyncReaderWriterLock();

async void ChangeState(bool state)
{
    using(await readerWriterLock.ReaderLockAsync())
    {
        await OutsideApi.ChangeState(state);
    }
}

async void DoStuff()
{
    using(await readerWriterLock.WriterLockAsync())
    {
        await OutsideApi.DoStuff();
    }
}
```

**n.b.** This solution still has the limitation that `DoStuff` calls could not be concurrent, writer lock, but still the order of the calls and the requirement to finalize all `DoStuff` before `ChangeState` and vice versa will be fulfilled.(tip from @Scott Chamberlain to use both reader and writer lock)

Comment: The solution doesn't support scenario of concurrent calls of the same method which is valid according to question. Even more as `SemaphoreSlim` doesn't guarantee order, the incoming calls can be postponed even if they arrive earlier. For instance while `ChangeState` is being executed and another `ChangeState` is triggered and afterwards `DoStuff` arrives the `DoStuff` can be reordered with second `ChangeState` which doesn't meet requirements.

Comment: Reminding me of AsyncEx was helpful. I think even a single AsyncLock used on both functions would be enough to satisfy the requirement. The ability to await the lock is a killer feature.

Comment: Using only a writer lock with no reader lock just turns this in to just a normal lock. You need ChangeState to be a ReaderLock to at least get this to have partial functionality of concurrent ChangeState calls (you still won't have concurrent DoStuff calls though).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The first solution didn't meet the requirements.

1. Create a custom lock class.
   This class keeps track of how many instances are running from which type (ChangeState and DoThing) and provides a way to check if a task can run.

```
        public class CustomLock
        {
            private readonly int[] Running;
            private readonly object _lock;
            public CustomLock(int Count)
            {
                Running = new int[Count];
                _lock = new object();
            }

            public void LockOne(int Task)
            {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    Running[Task]++;
                }
            }

            public void UnlockOne(int Task)
            {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    Running[Task]--;
                }
            }

            public bool Locked(int Task)
            {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Running.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (i != Task && Running[i] != 0)
                            return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

2. Change the already existing code.
   ChangeState will be task 0, and DoStuff will be task 1.

```
private CustomLock Lock = new CustomLock(2); //Create a new instance of the class for 2 tasks

async Task ChangeState(bool state)
{
   while (Lock.Locked(0)) //Wait for the task to get unlocked
      await Task.Delay(10);
   Lock.LockOne(0); //Lock this task
   await OutsideApi.ChangeState(state);
   Lock.UnlockOne(0); //Task finished, unlock one
}

async Task DoStuff()
{
   while (Lock.Locked(1))
      await Task.Delay(10);
   Lock.LockOne(1);
   await OutsideApi.DoStuff();
   Lock.UnlockOne(1);
}
```

While any ChangeState is running a new one can be started without waiting but when a DoStuff is called it will wait untill all ChangeStates finish, and this works the other way too.

Comment: I guess this would work. After digging into [AsyncEx](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx)'s sourcecode, it appears that it is very roughly doing the same thing in `AsyncLock`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ManualResetEvent or AutoResetEvent to signal that a thread has finished so that another thread can continue the work.

Some samples can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualresetevent?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.autoresetevent?view=netframework-4.7.2):

Answer (score 0):

I made for practice a synchronization primitive named `KeyedLock`, that allows concurrent asynchronous operations of only one key at a time. All other keys are queued, and unblocked later in batches (by key). The class is intended to be used like this:

```
KeyedLock _keyedLock;

async Task ChangeState(bool state)
{
    using (await this._keyedLock.LockAsync("ChangeState"))
    {
        await OutsideApi.ChangeState(state);
    }
}

async Task DoStuff()
{
    using (await this._keyedLock.LockAsync("DoStuff"))
    {
        await OutsideApi.DoStuff();
    }
}
```

For example the calls bellow:

```
await ChangeState(true);
await DoStuff();
await DoStuff();
await ChangeState(false);
await DoStuff();
await ChangeState(true);
```

...will be executed in this order:

```
ChangeState(true);
ChangeState(false); // concurrently with the above
ChangeState(true); // concurrently with the above
DoStuff(); // after completion of the above
DoStuff(); // concurrently with the above
DoStuff(); // concurrently with the above
```

The `KeyedLock` class:

```
class KeyedLock
{
    private object _currentKey;
    private int _currentCount = 0;
    private WaitingQueue _waitingQueue = new WaitingQueue();
    private readonly object _locker = new object();

    public Task WaitAsync(object key, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (key == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));
        lock (_locker)
        {
            if (_currentKey != null && key != _currentKey)
            {
                var waiter = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
                _waitingQueue.Enqueue(new KeyValuePair<object,
                    TaskCompletionSource<bool>>(key, waiter));
                if (cancellationToken != null)
                {
                    cancellationToken.Register(() => waiter.TrySetCanceled());
                }
                return waiter.Task;
            }
            else
            {
                _currentKey = key;
                _currentCount++;
                return cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested ?
                    Task.FromCanceled(cancellationToken) : Task.FromResult(true);
            }
        }
    }
    public Task WaitAsync(object key) => WaitAsync(key, CancellationToken.None);

    public void Release()
    {
        List<TaskCompletionSource<bool>> tasksToRelease;
        lock (_locker)
        {
            if (_currentCount <= 0) throw new InvalidOperationException();
            _currentCount--;
            if (_currentCount > 0) return;
            _currentKey = null;
            if (_waitingQueue.Count == 0) return;
            var newWaitingQueue = new WaitingQueue();
            tasksToRelease = new List<TaskCompletionSource<bool>>();
            foreach (var entry in _waitingQueue)
            {
                if (_currentKey == null || entry.Key == _currentKey)
                {
                    _currentKey = entry.Key;
                    _currentCount++;
                    tasksToRelease.Add(entry.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    newWaitingQueue.Enqueue(entry);
                }
            }
            _waitingQueue = newWaitingQueue;
        }
        foreach (var item in tasksToRelease)
        {
            item.TrySetResult(true);
        }
    }
    private class WaitingQueue :
        Queue<KeyValuePair<object, TaskCompletionSource<bool>>>
    { }

    public Task<Releaser> LockAsync(object key,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var waitTask = this.WaitAsync(key, cancellationToken);
        return waitTask.ContinueWith(
            (_, state) => new Releaser((KeyedLock)state),
            this, cancellationToken,
            TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
            TaskScheduler.Default
        );
    }
    public Task<Releaser> LockAsync(object key)
        => LockAsync(key, CancellationToken.None);

    public struct Releaser : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly KeyedLock _parent;
        internal Releaser(KeyedLock parent) { _parent = parent; }
        public void Dispose() { _parent?.Release(); }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -3):

This seems like a good fit for a pair of `ReaderWriterLockSlim`s.

```
private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim changeStateLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim doStuffLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
```

One controls the access to `ChangeState` and the other controls the access to `DoStuff`.

The reader lock is used to signal that a method is being executed and the writer lock is used to signal that the other method is being executed. `ReaderWriterLockSlim` allows multiple reads but writes are exclusive.

`Task.Yield` is just to yield control back to the caller because `ReaderWriterLockSlim`'s ar blocking.

```
async Task ChangeState(bool state)
{
    await Task.Yield();

    doStuffLock.EnterWriteLock();

    try
    {
        changeStateLock.EnterReadLock();

        try
        {
            await OutsideApi.ChangeState(state);
        }
        finally
        {
            changeStateLock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        doStuffLock.ExitWriteLock();
    }
}

async Task DoStuff()
{
    await Task.Yield();

    changeStateLock.EnterWriteLock();

    try
    {
        doStuffLock.EnterReadLock();

        try
        {
            await OutsideApi.DoStuff();
        }
        finally
        {
            doStuffLock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        changeStateLock.ExitWriteLock();
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is super easy to get in to a deadlock state. Call both methods at the same time with two threads and the system will permanently lock up. If you want to see it lock up reliably put a wait of a second or two  between the EnterWriteLock and EnterReadLock of both methods then run both methods on seperate threads.

Comment: I tried invoking both methods in quick succession, and got this error: System.Threading.LockRecursionException: Write lock may not be acquired with read lock held.This pattern is prone to deadlocks.Please ensure that read locks are released before taking a write lock. If an upgrade is necessary, use an upgrade lock in place of the read lock.

Comment: Yeap! Textbook mistake! :(